# Primitive roots mod $p^k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I'm having trouble understanding why this is true. Say m is the order of $g$ mod $2p^k$, with $\gcd(g, 2p^k)=1$, i.e. $g^m \equiv 1$ mod $2p^k$. How do I know that $g^m \equiv 1$ mod $p^k$?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $a \equiv b \bmod mn \implies a \equiv b \bmod m$.